# PHPMailer install without Composer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Please forgive my ignorance. 
I am trying to install PHPMailer 6.0.1 under PHP 5.6 on Linux. 
My PHP installation is remote and I manage all my websites’ PHP via FTP (I typically download packages as .zips to Win 10, unpack and then FTP the result to my webspace).

Of the various ways to install PHPMailer, Composer is preferred, but this is where I come unstuck.  None of the Composer instructions seems appropriate to this way of working – the installer wants me to the ‘Choose the command line PHP you want to use’, but I don’t have PHP locally ...
Annoyingly, I see PHPMailer’s composer.json file installed waiting to be used. 
But no PHPMailerAutoload.php (is this created by Composer?)

So I try to do a manual install of PHPMailer. I download, unzip and FTP upload the resulting directories to my webspace in folder PHPMailer. I then insert the following at the head of my PHP code and outside of any functions:

```
require_once 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

With the ‘use’ statements I get a syntax error *unexpected 'use' (T_USE)* …
Without them I get as far as trying to instantiate:
$mail = new PHPMailer; 
but this fails with a ‘class 'PHPMailer' not found

What please am I doing wrong and how can I do better?

Comment: Your life will be so much easier if you *do* get PHP locally. Having a local development environment is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't specific to PHPMailer - it's what you need to do to use any of the myriad PHP packages that use namespaces. The PHP docs on how to use `use` are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

The short version is, you need to put `namespace` and `use` directives before any other scripting, so if you simply reverse the order of your commands, it should work:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require_once 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Incidentally, this is the order used in the example in the PHPMailer readme and all the other examples provided with PHPMailer. You may find [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) useful too.

The `PHPMailerAutoload.php` file no longer exists - composer's autoloader does a much better job. PHPMailer's own `composer.json` file is used to resolve dependencies and flag compatibility requirements for your app's own composer file, that is, it's used to tell your project's composer file how to use PHPMailer – but is not your project's composer file itself – every package you load will have its own.

Developing without a local PHP instance is hard work – developing on your live server is, shall we say, "discouraged"! If you can't install PHP directly, run it in a container or VM using Docker, VirtualBox or something like XAMPP that's completely self-contained.

Comment: Reversing the order of 'use' and 'require' made no difference, but moving both to the head of the script worked - many thanks. Looking at the documentation for 'use', I am still unclear why this is the case since there is no prerequisite positioning apart from their being outside of any function (and, one assumes, preceding the instantiation of any class name defined within them).

Comment: It didn't occur to me that you didn't have them at the head of the script already.

Comment: The nonsense of `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer` works perfectly! use thanks\thanks\thanks.

Comment: where should i unzip my phpmailer in laravel project

Comment: You're doing something fairly wrong if you're using Laravel without composer. You shouldn't have to unzip it anywhere - just add the dependency to your `composer.json` file and composer will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 5):

In version 6.02, each of the phpmailer modules contain the namespace `PHPMailer\PHPMailer` declaration so the following works (no autoloader needed but this routine should be in `/src` folder):

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path_setup.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Comment: i lost 12 hours. Really PHPMailer need folder 'PHPMailer/src/'

Comment: don't forget to add both /PHPMailer & /PHPMailer/src to your paths.

Answer (score 1):

First create a  folder src and create Exception.php,PHPMailer.php,SMTP.php Liber's then we get results

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // use $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
$mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // ssl is depracated
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->setFrom('@gmail.com', '...');
$mail->addReplyTo('@gmail.com', ' Name');
$mail->addAddress('@gmail.com', '...');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("Hello test SMTP body"); //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__); //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
$mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported';
// $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png'); //Attach an image file

if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>*strong text*
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify you `require`, and try set like the wiki of PHPMailer says:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

[Link of wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: I don't think `PHPMailerAutoload.php` exists anymore in PHPMailer 6.0.1.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, i did't see his version. I'm use an older than 6.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Not passable without composer....

Warning: require(src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\testtest\test.php on line 5

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'src/Exception.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\testtest\test.php on line 5

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question