# How to send an e-mail from a server on which I can't install anything?

Tags: php

I am hosting my website on https://www.gandi.net/en , thing is they don't allow connections over ssh only sftp.
I have a form on my website and want to allow user to contact me through that form. In other words an e-mail needs to be sent from form@mydomain.com to me@mydomain.com.
In order to do that there are a couple of options I tried, but none of them seems to work:

1) PHP's `mail` function: doesn't support authentification. In order to send an e-mail from form@mydomain.com I need to authenticate. And that doesn't seem to be possible with the mail-function

2) PHPMailer: I saw many people recommending this solution. I downloaded their sources and had a look. It seems like in order for it to work you need to actually install PHPMailer using composer. I can't run composer via sftp...

What other solutions exist? Or what workaround exists?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to ask them? it seems they got lot of answers https://docs.gandi.net/en/gandimail/index.html

Comment: Use a third-party SMTP provider, example: https://serversmtp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) PHPMailer: I saw many people recommending this solution. I
>   downloaded their sources and had a look. It seems like in order for it
>   to work you need to actually install PHPMailer using composer. I can't
>   run composer via sftp...

You don't need to run composer, just download the PHPMailer files manually and upload it via sftp. Composer just makes it easier to install packages, the PHPMailer itself existed long before Composer was a thing.

If you don't know how to install it without Composer, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247149/phpmailer-install-without-composer).

Comment: Hmm, interesting! I tried as follows: `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; require_once 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';`but that doesn't seem to work. My files are organized on the same level as follows: `contact.php` and the directory `PHPMailer-master`

Comment: for clarification: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/23WDBNyv6n/ this only prints "Going to include" and my files are organized as follows: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/syPnPVZR7p/

Comment: My bad I made some stupid mistake! That being said, it keeps on loading forever and no e-mail is being sent... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can give swiftmailer a try: https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/

It is used by Yii2 Framework as well.

If I am not mistaken, for most if not all PHP extensions, you can integrate it into your website by using composer from your own development machine, and then you'd upload the source using FTP. You don't need to use composer on the host server.

I have used swiftmailer with Yii2 websites on a public host and I didn't have to do any special setup on the host.

If all else fails, change host. Get a refund and use your new host's web transfer services to move with minimum effort.

Comment: I at some point need to run the composer command with some arguments. I presume this will install and put a bunch of stuff in /usr/lib, some other places where it might be needed and set up my environment. So I don't see how this can work if I don't run `composer` on that remote server. Are you sure?

Comment: Composer just downloads PHP classes and other files required for the functionality you want to include in your website, and then auto loads the classes as needed. Once you have the files you need, you don't need to do anything else. The best way for you to know 100%, for your satisfaction, is to try it in a small test website.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you use a SPF TXT record in your DNS setup for their Simple Hosting package, you should be able to use `mail()` as-is without having to authenticate to your mail host:

```
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:217.70.176.0/21 ip6:2001:4b98:c::/48 ip4:217.70.185.10 ip4:173.246.97.150 ip4:217.70.186.165 ptr ?all"
```

Source:

http://wiki.gandi.net/en/dns/zone/spf-record

Which has this quote:

> This Simple Hosting records is only used if you plan to send e-mails through your website (via contact form, etc..)
>
> After you've submitted each of these changes, be sure to activate the new version of your zone file, and keep in mind that it will take about 3 hours for it to take full effect due to the standard DNS propagation delay.

You can confirm the SPF TXT record is deployed using various online SPF testing tools.

Since a lot of users have the ability to edit StackOverflow posts, I recommend going to the source and copying and pasting the appropriate SPF record directly to avoid shenanigans.  Also the Gandi Wiki will always have the latest list of IPs whereas this post may go stale after 6 months.

I recommend Composer-less CubicleSoft [Ultimate E-mail Toolkit](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ultimate-email) or one of the other already mentioned libraries over directly using the built-in PHP `mail()` function.  The PHP `mail()` function is very misleading.  It simply drops a properly prepared mail message into the mail queue on the local host.  However, e-mail is very complex and really needs a library even for the most basic PHP `mail()` use-cases.

If you want to use one of the other Composer-enabled libraries but don't want to upload thousands of little rinky-dink files that comes with Composer-enabled software, then check out CubicleSoft [Decomposer](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/php-decomposer).  Decomposer takes an entire Composer project tree and generates standalone builds with 1-2 files as the output.