# How can I use phpmailer without composer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I need to send emails and the `mail()` function just does not work for me.
The problem is that PHP is not installed on my device. Can I still use it in, `index.php` for example?

I use `000webhost`

Comment: If PHP isn't installed, a lot more than just `mail()` isn't going to work. If you want to use PHP, you need PHP installed on your server. In what *way* is `mail()` not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPMailer install without Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247149/phpmailer-install-without-composer)

Comment: @ceejayoz no im not getting an error. I am running it on a web server not localhost, the message sends, i use an if statement to echo a message if it sends, which it does, but i never receive it. I am still stuck

Comment: @ceejayoz it worked before but it does not all the sudden even without php installed

Comment: If you're not getting errors and the message sends, the likely explanation is that the emails are being blocked as spam.

Comment: @ceejayoz i thought about that, but I check the spam in the email account I sent it to, and they arent there. I don't know what is happenning

Comment: Spam doesn't always make it to the spam folder. In some cases, it'll be blocked entirely. Try sending to an email address with a different provider as a test.

Comment: 000webhost Free Web Hosting has full PHP support, so PHPMailer should work. What's the PHP code you use for it?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner like the code to send an email with PHPMailer?

Comment: Yes, I mean: what's the PHP code you use to send emails with PHPMailer? If you added it to your question, it could be useful to solve the issue.

Comment: This goes to my path but: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dvu0lY4LmvcO2EqSSkP0JODwOinGch5jmDXJgdhP8d8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (it works for me):

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'xxx';            // Change here
$mail->Password = 'xxx';            // Change here
$mail->setFrom('xxx', 'Mailer');    // Change here
$mail->addAddress('xxx');           // Change here
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body = 'Hello world';

echo $mail->Send() ? 'OK!' : 'Something went wrong';
```

Be sure that:

- the files `PHPMailer.php` and `SMTP.php` are in the same folder of the PHP script (I suggest you to put them all in the root of your website, for now);
- the PHP script (containing the above code) is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Ok. I will surely try that.