# PHP mailer Issues

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    require_once "php/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "php/SMTP.php";
    require_once "php/Exception.php";
    require_once "php/OAuth.php";
    require_once "php/POP3.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //smtp settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = 'xxxx';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    //email settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom("$email");
    $mail->addAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = ("Dal Website COntact FOrm");
    $mail->Body = ("Test");

if(!$mail->send()) {

echo 'Message was not sent.';

echo 'Mailer error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {

echo 'Message has been sent.';

}
?>
```

I have a folder called PHP which only has the PHP mailer Files, and this file is outside that directory, I personally think that its a directory issues but IDK know it's not even showing me a error please help me out.

Comment: So, what the actual issue is?

Comment: You do need to actually try to find the problem. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts).

Comment: @krylov123 It's not working bascially neither I'm getting a Error

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220766/how-can-i-use-phpmailer-without-composer/65239234#65239234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to include or require PHP mailer classes.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;    
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;    

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';    
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';    
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';    
?>
```

Please check the PHPMailer documentation for more details.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer